# Issue with displaying the image correctly in iPhone(3.5 retina inch)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2

I have to display the same image in iPhone and iPhone(3.5 retina inch). But it appears differently.

The original image looks like this:

[image]

It runs correctly in iPhone but it doesn't run correctly in iPhone(3.5 retina inch). In iPhone(3.5 retina inch), it appears like this:

[image]

I have tried this:

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```

The whole code looks like this:

```
if(IS_IPHONE_5)
    {
        // code for 4-inch screen
        backgroundImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
        backgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1_iphone5.png"];
   } else {
        // code for 3.5-inch screen
        backgroundImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 370);
       backgroundImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
        [backgroundImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"]];
    }
```

but this doesn't solve the problem. Have been stuck with this issue for a day. Not sure what the problem is. Really need some guidance.

Comment: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 370) seems to be problem.....change rect exactly as of image resolution and it should work....

Comment: the size is 640 x 733.. how to show the exact image? I need to resize right? even if that was the problem, i should have been a problem for iPhone as well.

Comment: Various screens have various DPI values. Thats why apple recommends different images for different phones. see this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW1

Comment: huh? I dun understand you.

Comment: Override `drawRect` method and use `[img drawInRect:rect];` to draw the image.

Comment: I added this: [backgroundImageView drawRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 370)]; Still no change..

Answer (score 0):

If you have one image for 4-inch and 3.5-inch devices the problem is probably in autoresizing mask, looks like now you have UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight on. Try setting UIViewAutoresizingNone instead.

Comment: Then in which method do you have this "(IS_IPHONE_5)" code? Are you using nib files?

Comment: UIViewAutoResizing issues fixed my very similar problem, +1 to @dariaa